# Golang Can someone explain why the compare of hash is fail

Tags: go, bcrypt

I am trying to develop a user login system, in order for that I am testing the bcrypt function of golang. But I faced some funny situation.

My bcrypt learning material is come from this, the code works well
https://medium.com/@jcox250/password-hash-salt-using-golang-b041dc94cb72

But when I wrote my own code, it keep fail in comparison.

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

func main() {
    hash1, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte("123456"), bcrypt.MinCost)
    hash2, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte("123456"), bcrypt.MinCost)

    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(hash1, hash2)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("success")
    }
}
```

Since the string for hashing is the same "123456", I except the output of my code should be `success`, but the outcome is `crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password`.

Can someone explain this and guide me.

Comment: the function you use is called "CompareHashAndPassword" not "CompareHashAndHash" it should work when you replace hah2 with "132456"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the function you are using says it compares a hash to a plaintext password - not a hash to a hash:

> CompareHashAndPassword compares a bcrypt hashed password with its possible plaintext equivalent. Returns nil on success, or an error on failure.

If you were to print or compare each of the generated hashes, they would not match exactly either (that's kind of the point). But you should be able to use the `CompareHashAndPassword` function to check if a password was used to generate the given hash.

Try this:

```
err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(hash1, []byte("123456"))
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
} else {
    log.Println("success")
}
```